# AWS CloudFormation Intrinsic function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The goal is to deploy Dynatrace Oneagent to a Windows EC2 using userdata. The Dynatrace token ARN is exported from a source stack. The token is then imported in the destination stack. However, the ${GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret} is resulting in an empty string. Do you know what could be the reason?

Output/export the parameter from the source stack

```html
GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret:
    Value: !Ref GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret
    Export:
      Name: GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret
    Description: The ARN of the Global Dynatrace Token Secret.
```

Destination stack importing the parameter from the source stack

```html
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub
    - |
      <powershell>
      ...
      ${InstallDynatraceOneAgent}
      ...
      </powershell>
      <persist>true</persist>
            
     - InstallDynatraceOneAgent: !Sub | 
        $DynatraceSecret = Get-SECSecretValue -SecretID "${GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret}".SecretString
        Write-Output "DynatraceSecret: $DynatraceSecret"
        Write-Output "GlobalDynatraceTokenSecretArn: ${GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret}"
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://xxx.live.dynatrace.com/api/v1/deployment/installer/agent/windows/default/latest?arch=x86&flavor=default' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = 'Api-Token $DynatraceSecret' } -OutFile 'Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.263.138.exe'   
        .\Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.263.138.exe --set-infra-only=false --set-app-log-content-access=true --quiet
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
        net STOP "Dynatrace OneAgent"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        net START "Dynatrace OneAgent"
       GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret: 
        Fn::ImportValue: GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret
```

Comment: You have "GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret" everywhere. This might be confusing. Probably, you should name it different for ${GlobalDynatraceTokenSecret} which is not same as export variable name.